# How can I remove an extra domain from the links in SendGrid HTML emails?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am sending email using sendgrid key in a bash script and usual utilities

```
payload='{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "'"$TO_EMAIL"'"
        }
      ],
      "subject": "'"$SUBJECT"'"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "'"$FROM_EMAIL"'"
  },
  "content": [
    {
        "type": "text/html", 
        "value": "<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>Hello You link <a href=\"replacement_link\">Click</a></body></html>"
    }
  ],
}'

updated_payload=$(echo -e "${payload/replacement_link/"$url"}")


curl -v --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "$updated_payload"
```

Everything works fine, but the links are always prepended with something strange URL, like:

http://url8393.mydomain.com/ls/click?upn=SDFGOSODFGJSGJOADJFGDSJFGSDJKFG....

How can I get rid of this "prefix", but only for the email that is being sent using my script? Leave as is for the others

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because you have [Click Tracking](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking) activated:

> Enabling Click Tracking causes all the links and URLs in your emails to be overwritten and pointed to either SendGrid’s servers or the domain you branded your link with so that any time a customer clicks a link, SendGrid can track those clicks. SendGrid can track up to 1000 links per email.

So you should be able to turn it off in the SendGrid dashboard.

Comment: Can I turn it off in send email API payload or headers?

Comment: No, you need to turn it off in the dashboard